# Como aumentar en 1 una variable alfanumerica tipo AAA00000000

Tags: php, mysql

Tengo un id con el siguiente formato:

```php
 `$id = END00000001;`
```

Y debo aumentarlo de a uno a medida que cargo nuevos datos. 
No puedo simplemente sumarle uno ya que es alfanumérica.
Alguna sugerencia de como puedo hacer?
Muchas gracias

Comment: Aumentarlo desde PHP o MySQL?

Comment: desde php, luego ingreso una nueva linea con ese id en la base de datos. mi duda es como aumentar en uno el numero desde php

Comment: depende, si la parte literal siempre tiene 3 dígitos lo puedes hacer con `substring`

Comment: Si, la parte de letras siempre son 3 caracteres. Utilice substr como tu dijiste y me funciona para tomar solo los números. Por ejemplo 00001234, pero al sumarle +1 al numero, lo cambia a 1235 en lugar de 00001235 que es lo que necesito. Sabes como puedo hacer para agregar los ceros faltantes a la izquierda? @the-breaker

Comment: Puedes usar `sprintf();` como indica esta respuesta (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1699958/formatting-a-number-with-leading-zeros-in-php).

Comment: Mantené "END" por un lado y el contador por otro. Lueog los concatenas cuanto lo tenés que usar.

Comment: @the-breaker más fácil y rápido utilizar el operador de incremento `++`

Comment: @Xerif, no tenia idea, siempre se aprende algo nuevo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tan fácil como utilizar los operadores de incremento o decremento, que funcionan con números y strings, ejemplo;

```
<?php
$id_inscripcion_old = 'AAA00000001';
// incrementamos en 1
++$id_inscripcion_old;

echo $id_inscripcion_old; // AAA00000002
```

Más información en el manual: https://www.php.net/manual/es/language.operators.increment.php

Comment: Mucho mas sencillo, no sabia que funcionaban en variables alfanumericas. gracias!

Answer (score 1):

Como dijeron en los comentarios utilice por un lado `substr` para separar los números de las letras, luego le sume 1 a los números y finalmente `str_pad` para agregar la cantidad de ceros a la izq que necesitaba.

```
$id_inscripcion_old = AAA00000001;
$num = substr($id_inscripcion_old,3); //Creo variable $num con los caracteres a partir de la posicion 3 $num = 00000001
$num = $num + 1; //Sumo 1. $num = 2
$numerosId = str_pad($num,8,'0',STR_PAD_LEFT); //Agrego los ceros a la izq que necesito para tener 8 dígitos $num = 00000002
//Id inscripcion completo
$id_inscripcion = $nombrecorto . $numerosId; //$id_inscriptcion = AAA00000002
```

Gracias a todos por los comentarios.

Comment: De nada, no olvides marcar tu respuesta como aceptada.